# How do I use a different android.app.Application object for tests?

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

I want use two different android.app.Application objects for running the app and testing.  This will allow me to have different setups for testing and running.

my `src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:name=".SampleApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and my `src/androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:name=".TestApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="Test Application"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and `MainActivityTest.java`

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class MainActivityTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(
            MainActivity.class);


    @Test
    public void response() throws Exception {
        TextView textView = (TextView) mActivityRule.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.text);
        String actualText = textView.getText().toString();
        Assert.assertEquals("foo", actualText);
    }
}
```

note how `android:name` point to the Application classes I want for each but it looks like the annotation is ignore in tests, TestApplication is never started.  Are the manifests not combined?  Is there a better approach for having swapping out these Application classes?

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at this [blog post](https://artemzin.com/blog/how-to-mock-dependencies-in-unit-integration-and-functional-tests-dagger-robolectric-instrumentation/). Specifically into last part "How to mock and inject dependencies in tests with Dagger 2 in Instrumentation tests?"

In short. Create you own custom runner

```
public class CustomInstrumentationTestRunner extends AndroidJUnitRunner {

  @Override
  @NonNull
  public Application newApplication(@NonNull ClassLoader cl, 
                                    @NonNull String className, 
                                    @NonNull Context context)
                                    throws InstantiationException, 
                                    IllegalAccessException, 
                                    ClassNotFoundException {
    return Instrumentation.newApplication(CustomApp.class, context);
  }
}
```

Apply it in `build.gradle`

```
android {  
  defaultConfig {
    testInstrumentationRunner 'a.b.c.CustomInstrumentationTestRunner'
  }
}
```

Examples are taken from blog post.

Regarding `src/androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml`. Don't be confused. This manifest is used for app which contains your tests code, not for app under test.